# How to delete some components of Solidworks assembly model imported from CATIA

Tags: solidworks, catia

I imported an airplane model (.CATProduct) to Solidworks. Now I want to delete some unnecessary components from the model. However, even if I right-click the model, I cannot find a delete button. How can I delete a component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make changes to the model using the following import settings:
[image: system options]

if you use 3D interconnect you are using a link to the actual files. If you use the old import then the original files get imported in bodies and surfaces, you can edit.

Comment: That totally makes sense! It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How did you import?
what soldiworks version are you using?
In SolidWorks 2021 you have to choose between 2 ways of importing:
[image]
If you used the graphics one, you will only get the model as in a viewer. I suspect that is what happened.
I don't know from what version exactly the 2nd was introduced.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am using SolidWorks 2021 and imported from ".catproduct", not the Graphics one, but I am not in a viewer mode, I believe. Is there any way I can check if I am in a viewer or not?

Comment: Can you drag components to another assembly? I don´t have catia files to test here. Is it possible to share a file?

Comment: Hello Eddy! No, I cannot drag the components.  Here is the link for the model: https://grabcad.com/library/f21-fighter-jet-1 The CATIA file of my interest is "FINAL PRODUCT - F21 FIGHTER JET". I want to remove a strange artifact near the cockpit.